# How to say "was mentioned on July 12th"?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

I need to say: "the first time this was mentioned was on July 12th," and I have written *la première fois que le gratin a été mentionné en le 12 juillet*. But that translates to "the first time the gratin was mentioned on July 12th." What?

Comment: Grammatically, that should be « mentionné »

Comment: Think you just need an *était* in there instead of *en*.

Comment: Yeah it's for a cookbook.

Answer (score 3):

You could also say: "La première mention date du 12 juillet".

Note that in French, months are not capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

If the sentence is about a *"gratin"* already mentionned, in english, you replace by *this*, in french you can replace by *"cela"*.

You cannot translate "this was mentionned **on** July 12th." by *"cela a été mentionné **en le** 12 juillet."* because in french, you talk first about the day. So you have to translate into *"mentionné **le** 12 Juillet."*

Moreover, you forgot one verb in your translation :
"the first time this **was mentioned**(1) **was**(2) on July 12th," => *"la première fois que le gratin **a été mentionné**(1) en le 12 juillet,"*.

I would then translate

> the first time this was mentioned was on July 12th,

into

> la première fois que cela a été mentionné était le 12 Juillet,

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use *évoquer* or *aborder* here :

> Le gratin a été évoqué pour la première fois le 12 juillet.

or if you want to emphasize the date:

> Le 12 juillet, le gratin a été évoqué pour la première fois.